# Is satisfaction relation for higher order formulas and a fixed structure always (equivalent to) $\Pi^0_1$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In the semantics of higher order languages, if the domain is $D$, then the $n$-th quantifiers range over $P^{n-1}(D)$. Is there something wrong in the following argument?

---

The (pseudo-)proof:

For every formula $\phi$ of order $n>1$ define property $S_\phi(\frak{A})$ to be
$$
\mathfrak{A}\models\phi
$$
Suppose $\mathfrak{A} = (A,\in,\ldots)$. We translate $\phi$ to $\phi'$ as follows:

1. Replace all the quantifiers of order $m<n$ with a first order quantifier bound to $P^{m-1}(A)$.
2. Replace all the quantifiers of order $n$ with an unbound first order quantifier.

$\phi'$ is first order. Let $\frak{A}^*$ denotes $(P^{n-1}(A),\in,\ldots)$. It follows that $S_\phi(\frak{A})$ iff $S_{\phi'}(\frak{A}^*)$. Since first order satisfaction is $\Delta^0_0$, power set operation is $\Pi^0_1$, it follows that $S_\phi(\frak{A})$ is equivalent to $\Pi^0_1$.

Comment: Where does your 'It seems that' assertion come from?

Comment: $\Delta_0^0$ over $P(A)$ (I presume you mean the powerset?) isn't the same as $\Delta_0^0$ over $A$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I should have said that the structure is fixed. First, make all the first quantifiers bounded to $A$. Then, higher order quantifiers can be replaced with bounded first order quantifiers. For example, a second order quantifier $\forall X$ can be replaced with $\forall x\in P(A)$.

Comment: Then my second comment applies — $\forall x\in P(A)$ is a first-order quantifier in $P(A)$ but that's not the same as being a first-order quantifier in $A$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, I am aware of that. But the satisfaction relation itself is always first order since we are working in first order set theory.  Also apologies for the previous confusions. I've edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'first order'. There's 'first order with respect to a structure'. Second-order logic in $A$ is equivalent to first-order logic in $P(A)$ (or more properly $A^A$, but there's something like a bijection, so.) Every second-order formula, e.g. something like $\forall U:A\mapsto A.\forall V:A\mapsto A.\exists W:A\mapsto A.\forall a\in A.W(a)=U(V(a))$, has a first-order version in $A^A$, but that doesn't mean the same thing as being first-order in $A$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Isn't it first order with respect to the set universe $V$?